# Keeping the fancy sudo warning forever

Tags: linux, sudo

The first time I do `sudo` on openSUSE I'm always warned with a someway fancy message

```
We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

root's password:
```

After the first successful login I won't be warned again.

I'd like to be always warned. I find this message someway fancy. Is there any way to be warned like that by sudo prompt?

Comment: To be honest if this shows every time I use `sudo`, I will still manage to ignore it and remove root directory or something like that. This will probably only work if the warning is a 3d banner blinking with multiple color which is different every time.

Comment: @NgSekLong I've seen (boring|terrible|lazy|startup character) ASCII banners in conjunction with poor system administration skills before. I guess it's not that simple but… uh challenge accepted? https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/07/view-gifs-on-the-command-line-because-why-not-right At worst you loose your compliance status, or even worse it's mandatory in the next revision of whatever rules you have to implement at work.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Create a file inside /etc/sudoers.d/ You can use this command

```
sudo nano /etc/sudoers.d/privacy
```

Now paste this line into the file.

```
Defaults        lecture = always
```

Now close Terminal/Konsole, Reopen it and try to do something with sudo.

Comment: Can I also disable the message by setting `lecture` to `never`?

Comment: Yes, the options for **lecture** are: `always` `never` `once`
[sudoers man](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.13/sudoers.man.html)

Comment: Can I reduce this to one line? `$ sudo echo "Defaults lecture = always" >> /etc/sudoers.d/privacy` gives permission denied.

Comment: `$ sudo echo "Defaults lecture = always" | sudo tee -a /etc/sudoers.d/privacy`

Comment: You don't need the `sudo` on the `echo`

Comment: Using `sudoedit` would be a lot safer than `sudo nano` - if something goes wrong, you may not be able to run sudo again to fix it

Answer (score 7):

To re-set an account to see the warning once more, delete the sudo records for that user.

```
root>  rm  /var/lib/sudo/<username>/*
root>  rmdir /var/lib/sudo/<username>
```

Comment: According to `man sudoers` on a CentOS 7 host, the default setting for `lecture_status_dir` is `/var/db/sudo/lectured`

Answer (score 4):

To add to [Michael JAMES's statement](https://superuser.com/a/749833/910769), locations might vary.
On Fedora,

```
rpm -ql sudo
```

Shows a directory called:

```
/var/db/sudo
```

In this directory i found another directory called 'lectured' followed by my name. Removing my name from this directory show the warning again.

Edit: This is a one time solution to reset showing the message. You could of course use crontab to empty the directory so that the message is printed on a more regular basis.

Comment: What does `rpm -ql` do, and is there a debian-equivalent?